# My widgets are not displayed in java (swing)

Tags: java, swing, java-11, event-dispatch-thread

I'm new to java, and I have a bug that I've been trying to fix for hours.

I have the following code:

```
package MatchMe;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class InterfazMatchMe extends JFrame{
    private ControllerMatchMe controller;
    private Boolean pressButton = false;
    private int SIZE_SQUARES_ARRAY = 8;
    private JPanel squaresArea;
    private Listener listener;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel square;
    private JButton match;
    private Timer timer;
    // Son importantes para que la clase 'Listener' sepa de estas
    private GridBagConstraints constraints;
    private Squares focusSquares[];
    private int dificult;
    private int id;
    
    InterfazMatchMe() {
        initGUI();
        this.setTitle("Match Me");
        this.setSize(800, 700); //800, 650
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public void initGUI() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        listener = new Listener();
        controller = new ControllerMatchMe();
        squaresArea = new JPanel();
        generateButton();
        timer = new Timer(2000, listener);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void generateButton() {
        match = new JButton("MATCH");
        match.addActionListener(listener);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 3;
        constraints.gridwidth  = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        add(match, constraints);
    }
    
    // this method does not work well
    public void game() {
        while(true) {
            this.dificult = controller.getDificult();
            Squares squares[] = controller.getSquares();
            Squares shuffleSquares[] = controller.shuffleArray(squares);
            Squares filteredSquares[] = controller.extractSpecificLength(shuffleSquares, dificult);
            while(true)
            {
                this.id = controller.changeElement(shuffleSquares, filteredSquares, dificult);
                this.focusSquares = controller.setFocus(id, filteredSquares, true);
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                    generateSquaresArray(focusSquares, dificult, constraints);
                    break;
                }
                controller.setFocus(id, focusSquares, false);
                System.out.println(3);
                if(controller.getAciertos() % 3 == 0 && controller.getPermissionsChangeDificult()) {
                    controller.setPermissionsChangeDificult(false);
                    controller.setDificult(dificult+1);
                    break;
                }
                else if(controller.getMatch()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void generateSquaresArray(Squares[] focusSquares, int dificult, GridBagConstraints constraints) {
        int x=0, y=0;
        
        for(int i=0; i<dificult; i++) {
            image = new ImageIcon("src/Images/"+focusSquares[i].getId()+".jpg");
            square = new JLabel(image);
            constraints.gridx = x;
            constraints.gridy = y;
            constraints.gridwidth  = 1;
            constraints.gridheight = 1;
            constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            if(x == 3) {x = 0;y = 1;} else {x += 1;}
            squaresArea.add(square, constraints);
        }
        squaresArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310, 180));
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth  = 2;
        constraints.gridheight = 2;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        add(squaresArea, constraints);
    }
    
    public void userInteraction(String answer) {
        controller.updateStatusGame(answer, focusSquares, dificult, id);
            
        if(controller.getGoodGame()) {
            System.out.println("\nBien hecho, has sumado 5 puntos\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\nMuy mal, tienes una vida menos\n");
            if(controller.getPlayerLives() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Game over !!!\n");
                System.out.print(controller.getStatisticsPlayer());
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class Listener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(2);
            if(event.getSource() == match) {
                pressButton = true;
                userInteraction("y");
                pressButton = false;
            }
            if(pressButton == false ) {
                userInteraction("n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> In the code, there is a method that has this comment: this method does
> not work well

The problem is the following. Those System.out.print you see are repeating like they never got out of the loop.

On the other hand the widgets are not shown. Understanding by widget the "squares" that are generated in a JPanel called "squaresArea" and the "match button".

If I comment on the "game()" function, which is the one with this bug, the program behaves without any problem.

I ask for your help, I have already tried everything.

Comment: `while(true)` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. **BTW:** `this.setSize(800, 700);` That size is no better than a guess as to how big the GUI needs to be. Call `pack()` instead to have the GUI be the exact right size.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

I was looking at the link, and discovered something called "worker threads", these claim to be good for when you have a long-running task.

My whiles are long lasting. Will this type of thread be the most appropriate for my application?

I think so, but I don't know what you think about it.

Comment: It'd probably be better to use a Swing `Timer` that does each iteration of the loop in a single action. Each loop itself should not take long. Vahing said that, I didn't notice at first that: a) There were ***3 nested*** `while(true)` loops. b) Al least one of the loops was adding components. c) They call a method that loads an image. --- C) Don't load images repeatedly. Load them once at start-up and keep a reference to them to be used later. B) Components added after the GUI becomes visible require special handling, though usually the best approach is to update the state of existing GUI. ..

Comment: A) .. I have not looked closely enough at the code to figure out the logic of the triple loop.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I'll keep it in mind. At the moment I have just implemented a worker thread for the "game" method and it seems to be going well ... the only thing that still does not work is that the squares do not appear in the GUI, so I will look at their advice in detail to see if maybe hopefully I can solve the problem.

Comment: By the way, I just deleted the middle while (the second one) because it didn't make much sense ...

Even so, my images are not shown on the button (which by the way, the button already appears)

Comment: *"my images are not shown on the button"* Problems should be broken down into smaller parts. Having said that, *`ImageIcon("src/Images/"+focusSquares[i].getId()+".jpg");`* Like I said, ***don't*** try loading them in the loop(s). Instead load that on initialization. Given doing that, show them in a `JOptionPane` immediately on load to check they are at the path expected. I have reasons to believe they are not..